# Product not Showing in category page when enabel grouped product in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Added one grouped product in the category. In the home page product list it showing that grouped product, but when I redirect to the category page, none of product showing. when I disabled that grouped product, In category page show all products.

Some of them prefer do Reindex and cache clean. I did the all stuff. but no luck.

Comment: what exactly you did? I need to show it

Comment: Is it live URL?